# Animation display issue in Google Chrome only

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome, animation

My website is the following URL:  http://bmgzstrategies.com/#casestudies

When I click on a thumbnail and then try and use the advance arrows, the animation behaves really horribly and flashes in and out of display.  This seems to only happen in Chrome on screen sizes above 1500 on certain screen resolutions, equally on Mac and PC, but behaves normally in Safari, Opera, and Firefox.  There are no error on Chrome developer tools.

Anybody know what could be going on?

Comment: I didn't see any flash in the images using the method you describe (Mac OSX 10.9, Chrome 27 stable), but sometimes image flash can be fixed by adding `webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;` to the div holding the picture.

Comment: Thank you for your inspiration!!! I am not sure what was creating the issue, but by forcing z-index values I was able to resolve the issue!  Thank you!!